# Initializer calling itself using swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I have this initializer:

```
    convenience required init(){
        print("Creating Object")
        self.init()
    }
```

When this code runs all I see in the console is a continuous stream of "Creating Object" lines even though I'm only creating a single instance of the object. It is clear from the print statements that `self.init()` is calling the `convenience required init()` method. Why would `self.init()` be calling the convenience initializer when apple makes it pretty clear that:

> A designated initializer must call a designated initializer from its
>   immediate superclass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the apple developer docummentation:

> Convenience initializers are secondary, supporting initializers for a
>   class. You can define a convenience initializer to call a designated
>   initializer from the same class as the convenience initializer with
>   some of the designated initializer’s parameters set to default values.
>   You can also define a convenience initializer to create an instance of
>   that class for a specific use case or input value type.

You do not have to provide convenience initializers if your class does not require them. Create convenience initializers whenever a shortcut to a common initialization pattern will save time or make initialization of the class clearer in intent.

**Initializer Delegation for Class Types**

To simplify the relationships between designated and convenience initializers, Swift applies the following three rules for delegation calls between initializers:

Rule 1
A designated initializer must call a designated initializer from its immediate superclass.

Rule 2
A convenience initializer must call another initializer from the same class.

Rule 3
A convenience initializer must ultimately call a designated initializer.

A simple way to remember this is:

Designated initializers must always delegate up.
Convenience initializers must always delegate across.

**So insure your convenience initializer and your required initializer do not have the same signature, which at present they do.  Which is why you're calling the initializer recursively endlessly**

Comment: nope. i got an error when i called super.init(): `Convenience initializer for 'Object' must delegate (with 'self.init') rather than chaining to a superclass initializer (with 'super.init')`

Comment: I'd suggest providing an example of what to do instead as well.